# Изменение текста в готовом div'е

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пишу простой editor html. Как реализовать изменение текста в уже готовом div'? Т.е. есть готовый HTML файл, нужно чтобы по нажатию на определённый блок была возможность сразу менять текст, как это делает devtools в хроме при "просмотре кода элемента". Задача не из стандартных видимо :) Надеюсь есть идеи)

Comment: Что Вы уже пробовали делать?

Comment: Если вы даже не представляете с чего вам начать подобное, то не стоит этим заниматься, это очень сложный велосипед. Посмотрите в сторону готовых решений и доработайте их, если вас, что то не устраивает в их функционале.

Comment: Ничего неточного в вопросе не вижу, уточнил как мог. Товарищ с ником Maqsood успешно на него ответил, просто не мог найти тот самый тег, дело остаётся за малым - реализовать отправку изменённого фрагмента, думаю использовать AJAX без скрытых форм (по функции click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то Вам нужно добавить атрибут **`contenteditable`**
Например, данный div будет работать как textarea:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  Здесь текст для редактирования
</div>
```

Для сохранения изменений в тексте, можно обработать посредством jQuery. Но одним `contenteditable` не обойтись, нужно отправлять измененные данные через скрытые формы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ответ, но по поводу отправки формы. Через AJAX не вариант? Просто с помощью JQuery брать контент блока и передавать его через тот же POST *.php скрипту? Без всяких скрытых форм.

Comment: @JohnKindle, Тоже верно! Вы можете получить данные DIV'а таким образом `$("div").text()` и отправлять его куда нужно)

Comment: Попробую обязательно! Спасибо большое!